# Preprocesor flag on Cocoapod podspec

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, preprocessor

I am building a framework that uses a preprocesor flag in one of the methods. Something like the following code:

```
public func heyStuck(overflow: String) {
    #if DEBUG
        print(overflow)
    #else
        print("¯\\_(ツ)_//¯")
    #endif
}
```

The point is that I am using Cocoapods to import my framework so, in order to define the flag DEBUG for the framework, I have to do something like this in my App Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            if config.name != 'Release'
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'DEBUG=1']
        end
        end
    end
end
```

Is there any way to add this information to the podspec file in order to avoid Apps to define this thing on their Podfile?

Answer (score 11):

I finally got it, using the following magic in my podspec file:

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {
  'OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS[config=Debug]' => '-DDEBUG',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with [prefix_header_contents](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#prefix_header_contents). For example:

```
s.prefix_header_contents = #define DEBUG 1
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam but doesn't work in swift since there is no #ifdef. I finally got it adding a conditional compilation flag just for Debug. I added the answer as an answer. Thanks again